# Changing xamarin android launcher theme that even applicable to preview window

Tags: android, xamarin, themes, android-launcher

I use a style as theme for my splash activity that also is MainLauncher. This is my splash screen drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   <item
android:id="@+id/itemSplashScreenBackgroundColor">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAppOrangeTheme" />
</shape>   </item>   <item>
<bitmap
android:src="@drawable/LogoSplashScreen"
android:tileMode="disabled"
android:gravity="center" />   </item> </layer-list>
```

And here is my style.xml file that uses mentioned drawable:

```
<resources>   <style name="styleAppSplashScreenTheme"
parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/XMLFileSplashScreen</item>
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>   </style> </resources>
```

As you see, to start my app quickly (user see app interaction quickly after tap app icon) I use value of windowDisablePreview as false.

Now I change background color of the splash screen by below coding in Activity OnCreate method:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable)ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.XMLFileSplashScreen);
            GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable)layerDrawable.FindDrawableByLayerId(Resource.Id.itemSplashScreenBackgroundColor);

            if (stringAppThemeName == "Orange")
            {
                gradientDrawable.SetColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.colorAppOrangeTheme));
            }
            else if (stringAppThemeName == "Blue")
            {
                gradientDrawable.SetColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.colorAppBlueTheme));
            }
base.OnCreate(bundleSavedInstanceState);
```

The problem is here when I relaunch the app it first loads the style with its default color (@color/colorAppOrangeTheme) for a moment then changes to desired color!

Several solutions I saw like setting windowDisablePreview to true but I don't want to void of preview window, I want to change color of splash screen background color even in preview window.

Please suggest applicable solution. Thanks.

Comment: You can not conditionally change the drawable of your `windowBackground` in a theme, you would have to just not include it. Or just make it black, or use your app logo, etc...

Comment: OK. Do you know when, where and how android uses theme to draw window preview?